# Unable to match child of a child from local storage Firebase RealTime database

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database, local-storage

My database structure is like this

[image]

And I want to Match the child under Generator with my local storage data if data matches I want to show the details of number present under Generator. but when i am matching the number by calling the number from local storage my code doesn't work but when i right the same value manually in the code my code start working.

code:-

```js
var deviceRef = app.database().ref('/All_machines/Generator/' + localStorage.getItem('machineid'));//machineid = numbers present under genrator.
deviceRef.on('child_added', function (data) {
  //Ambient temperature
  if (data.key === 'ambT') {
    console.log(data.val()); //This console not give me any data
    $('#ambient_temp .value').html(data.val());
    temp = data.val()
  }
  })
  
  // when I change the localStorage.getItem('machineid') to hardcoded number like this 8c96aa286f24 my code start working 
  
  //This code is working  only by hardcoding the Machineid 
  
  var deviceRef = app.database().ref('/All_machines/Generator/' + ' 8c96aa286f24');//machineid = numbers present under genrator.
deviceRef.on('child_added', function (data) {
  //Ambient temperature
  if (data.key === 'ambT') {
    console.log(data.val()); //but this gives me exact data if i hardcoded the values
    $('#ambient_temp .value').html(data.val());
    temp = data.val()
  }
  })
```

I have check the value in local storage and the value is accurate

`when i call  console.log(localStorage.getItem('machineid')) right before var deviceRef = app.database().ref('/All_machines/Generator/' + localStorage.getItem('machineid')); i get the accurate output:-  8c96aa286f24`

Comment: If you `console.log(localStorage.getItem('machineid'))` right before using it to access the database, what does it show? Please edit your question to include the updated code, and its output.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen i get  8c96aa286f24 which is accurate

Comment: Hmm.... I'm not sure what's going on ther.e Please edit your question again to show the updated single code snippet and its exact, complete output of both the new value I asked for the the output from the existing `console.log` statement.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen console.log(data.val()) this console is not giving any output on console

Answer (score 0):

While calling the data from local storage  `localStorage.getItem('machineid')` my data comes with a extra space like this `' 8c96aa286f24'` this is the reason why my code was not working i updated the code like this

```js
var machine_id_2 = localStorage.getItem('machineid')
 var space = machine_id_2.split(" ")
var machine_id_1 = space[1]

var deviceRef = db.ref('/All_machines/Generator/' + machine_id_1);
deviceRef.on('child_added', function (data) {
  //Ambient temperature
  if (data.key === 'ambT') {
    console.log(data.val());
    $('#ambient_temp .value').html(data.val());
    temp = data.val()
  }
  })
```